# what will be the exact position of the Thirty Meter Telescope

Tags: telescope

TMT will be put at Mauna Kea in Hawaii. It should be near Keck and Gemini.
However it seems there is no place left at that site.
What is the exact position?

[image: Mauna Kea]

Comment: This question isn't about astronomy, it's about buildings.